# UILabel text is not updated even in MainThread

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, dispatch-async

`UILabel.text` is not updated inside the main thread. `labelOne` is updated but `labelTwo` which is to show translated word is not updated. When I print `translatedWord` it prints right string to console but `UILabel` is not updated.

```
datatask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
    if error == nil {
        let receivedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.labelOne.text = wordTobeTranslated

            let data = "\(String(describing: receivedData!["text"]))"
            let all =   data.components(separatedBy: "(")
            let afterAll = all[2]
            let last = afterAll.components(separatedBy:")" )

            self.translatedWord = last[0]

            self.importantWords.append(last[0])
            self.labelTwo.text = self.translatedWord
            print(self.translatedWord)
        }
    }
})
datatask?.resume()
```

Comment: tried to print `translatedWord` and verfied it's not empty

Comment: it prints right as I mentioned above

Comment: did you manage to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to debug your issue:

1. Try to set some hard coded string to labelTwo and check whether it
   is displaying. (or)
2. Update any value for labelTwo in Storyboard and check whether is is
   displaying.

If string is displayed from any of the above steps, then labelTwo is configured correctly in storyboard.

You can also try `self.labelTwo.layoutIfNeeded()` method after updating the text to force update the UI.

If none of the steps helps you, check the Font color of UILabel. If it is same as background color, it would not be seen.

Comment: hardcoded string works. it is not initiated in StoryBoard by AutoLayout. it is initiated in subviewsdidlayout() and I change the position of the parentView of that labels before getting translated word.

Comment: and I changed that UILabel to UITextView. String is shown but I have to scroll to bottom to see that

Comment: Can you still retain UILabel and try layoutIfNeeded() in it?

Comment: tried it but did not work. I also print as print(labelTwo.text!) it prints the string I wanted but it is not shown. isn't it weird

Comment: Please check the font color of UILabel. If it is same as background color, then it would not be seen.

Comment: The string had linebreaks so it didnt show up in label. it is solved by removing line breaks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample, it would appear that you’re trying to retrieve:

```
describing: receivedData!["text"]
```

from:

```
\(String(describing: receivedData!["text"]))
```

The problem is that the `\(...)` in a `String` literal results in [string interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292) where the expression inside `\(` and `)` will be evaluated and that’s what will be place in the string. And the `String(describing: ...)` will interpret the value and return a string representation. So, let’s say that `receivedData!["text"]` contained the word “Foo”. Then

```
let data = "\(String(describing: receivedData!["text"]))"
```

Would result in `data` containing the string, `Optional("Foo")`.

If you want to remove that `Optional(...)` part, you should either unwrap the optional or use a `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`. And frankly, rather than using string interpolation at all, I’d just do:

```
let data = String(describing: receivedData?["text"] ?? "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for new searchers: Try setting number of lines of UILabel to Zero. It might be a constraints issue.